# strange dates in ROS' bags

Tags: ros, rosbag, timestamp

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hello everyone.
I'm trying to record the messages published to two topics inside a bag.
The creation of .bag file is created correctly, but when I write

```
rosbag info subset.bag
```

this is what I get:

```
path:        subset.bag
version:     2.0
duration:    3:45s (225s)
start:       Jan 01 1970 01:36:56.10 (2216.10)
end:         Jan 01 1970 01:40:41.30 (2441.30)
size:        20.5 MB
messages:    4507
compression: none [28/28 chunks]
types:       nav_msgs/Odometry     [cd5e73d190d741a2f92e81eda573aca7]
             sensor_msgs/LaserScan [90c7ef2dc6895d81024acba2ac42f369]
topics:      /base_scan   2254 msgs    : sensor_msgs/LaserScan
             /odom        2253 msgs    : nav_msgs/Odometry
```

How is it possible that ROS saves messages as I had sent them in 1970?
Thanks for help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/49257/strange-dates-in-ros%27-bags/) by [ubisum](https://answers.ros.org/users/3549/ubisum/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2012-11-27

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This looks like time offsets to me. I.e. the timestamps written are not absolute, but "time since running" or something like that.

Unix time starts at Jan 01 1970, 00:00.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2012-11-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ubisum](https://answers.ros.org/users/3549/ubisum/) on 2012-12-23**:
how can i modify timestamp of bag already generated? thanks

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-01-08**:
Look into rosbag filter.